# linux Getting Data From File

Tags: linux

I have a file where I save data to in the following format:

```
 admin = 123456
```

what I am trying to do is find that line in a file with 15 lines all with a unique name at the beginning. I can use grep from the terminal and i can get the line but I only want the 123456 bit of the line using bash script.

How would I read the line into the script and then get the password to compare to the password entered by the user. I can compare the passwords but getting it from the file is wherenI am stuck.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

admin=$(awk -F"[ \t]*=[ \t]*" '$1 == "admin" { print $2 }' file)
echo $admin
# => 12345
```

Comment: And is quite elegant.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep admin $YOUR_FILE_NAME | tr -d ' '| cut -d '=' -f2
```

Comment: and how is this saved into a variable?

Comment: MYVAR=\`grep admin $YOUR_FILE_NAME | tr -d ' '| cut -d '=' -f2\`

You might want to have a look at the [Advanced bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Comment: @NoLiver92  this is your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Simplest command I can think is

```
#!/bin/bash

value=`grep admin filename | cut -d' ' -f3`
echo $value
```

Comment: I need it in a variable grep doesnt do that, or does it?

Comment: To get the output of a command as a string, enclose it in backticks or in `$()`. Without those, your variable will say literally `"grep admin <file location>"` or whatever.

Comment: Works only if whitespace is actually present. See me solution, which works regardless if whitespace is present or not. Also the variable assignment is unnecessary.